# Copy or Share Report Header to all reports in solution - ssrs2008

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008

I am working on a report project in SSRS 2008. There will be 14 reports (separate rdl files) in this project and I want to use the exact same header design for all of them.  I have created the header in the first report, is there a way either save the header (it has a couple images, background color and a couple textboxes, one with an expression) as a single object which can them be copied to each report, or maybe create each new report based off this one report, then I can just change the dataset?  Thanks.

Comment: This link may be helpful for others: https://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/52182.ssrs-apply-consistent-headers-and-footers-to-deployed-reports.aspx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Report Builder 3.0:
The most straightforward way to do this is the old "Save As" trick. (Save a copy of your original report under a new name and use the copy to make a new report)
You could also locate the header block in your .rdl xml section and copy and paste that into your finished reports, but that is more likely to generate difficult to trace errors.